# Assembly programming sms32v50

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I am new to assembly. I have recently come across the DB command to store a string to the RAM.

I am looking for the most efficient way to copy the string to the VDU.

For example i use DB "TOP"
the T would be stored at ram location 08 and i want to copy all the characters to the VDU starting at location C0

Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Depends. A simple loop usually works, but you can also use `rep movsb` but that needs some code to set up. For short copies with compile-time sizes (such as if you always need to copy 3 bytes), you can use a few `mov` instructions too.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i have tried the mov instructions however all together im moving about 15 bytes from different locations and im very limited in memory

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently you are optimizing for size. `rep movsb` could then be useful:

```
mov si, 8
mov di, 0xc0
mov cx, 15
rep movsb
```

This is 11 bytes of code, assuming `DS` and `ES` are already set up properly, along with `DF`.

Comment: There are no SI DI CX registers in that assembker

Comment: @Artur: The question is tagged `[x86-16]`; this answer is for that architecture, and works on any x86 including original 8086.  http://www.softwareforeducation.com/sms32v50/ appears to be based on x86, but if it's not actually x86 then maybe you can clarify.